# Is there a word for "25 years" like "bicentennial" for 200 years? Is it "Quadranscentennial"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was looking for a word that means "25 years" in the way that "bicentennial" refers to 200 years.

Wikipedia suggests "Quadranscentennial", but I can't find extensive use of that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary

Is there any word for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Quarter of a century? That's the most common

Comment: If you are writing and you native tongue is not English, I would avoid anything other than a quarter century or 25 years.

Answer (score 8):

A 25th anniversary is a **silver jubilee** or **silver anniversary**, and a celebration of that milestone would be a **Silver Jubilee**.

The corresponding 50th anniversary is a **golden jubilee**, after which usage varies; when celebrating personal achievements it is a *diamond jubilee* at 60 and *platinum* at 70, as in the reign of a monarch, but the 75th anniversary of the founding of the Boy Scouts of America, for example, was a *diamond jubilee*.

If you want to mark a period of time rather than the milestone, then **quarter century** would do the trick as well as simply saying *25th anniversary* or *25 years*.

Comment: You didn't answer the asked question, which is to find a word  of the same form as bicentennial.

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the those terms. But I'm looking for a word like `bicentennial`.

Comment: The stated question was "a word that means '25 years' in the way that 'bicentennial' refers to 200 years." I provided a phrase, but a phrase that means 25 years and which I use in the exact scenarios I use "bicentennial." If that's not sufficient, the OP needs to revise the question and be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

Note the comments entry for ***quadranscentennial*** as a term for 25th anniversary in that Wikipedia link:

> Probably a modern coined term

Probably correct, in my opinion.

There are a few usages of quadranscentennial as a 25th anniversary event e.g. the **[Bhutan Quadranscentennial of Apollo 11 commemorative stamp](http://www.spaceandastronomystamps.com/btn14.xhtml)** issued in 1994. But I am uncertain if that was a transcription or spelling error, as I could not find any confirmation from an official Bhutan website.

For wedding commemoration, or regency, a term in current use is "Silver Anniversary". Or "Silver Jubilee" in the case of regents. It isn't a Latin-ate term. But it **is** a commonly understood term.

- **[Quadricentennial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadricentennial)** refers to the 400th anniversary of an event.

Answer (score 1):

If *semicentennial* (*semi-*, precisely half, + *centennial*, a period of 100 years) is 50 years, then *quarticentennial* (*quart-*, a combining form meaning "a fourth," + *centennial*) is properly the *-ennial* word meaning 25 years (and arguably more correct than *quadrancentennial*, since there is no combining form of *quadrant*).

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, quadranscentennial is the technical term and it is not widely used.  I have seen either:

- 25th Anniversary or
- Every 25 years

Depending on whether you're talking about a one-time event (like a wedding anniversary) or a repeating event (none come to mind).

Comment: In this case, its my 25th birthday, and I'd like a nice word to describe the achievement of having survived for a quarter century. :)

Comment: In that case I would go with Silver Birthday, as others have said.  I don't think a cooler name exists.

Answer (score 0):

A period of 25 years is a "Generation". The time from birth to someone having a child of their own and starting the next generation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to coin words try Latin-English **viginti-quinque-ennial**. Latin **viginti** is twenty, **quinque** five.

Comment: One can do better than that:http://languagehat.com/dodrans/

Comment: You should know how to place words in italics or bold, it would make your answers so much *clearer*!

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I should try to learn it. There are so many typographical tricks on Este that I never dared to study the help pages.

Comment: Place one * before and after the word or phrase for *italics* and two ** before and after (no spaces) for **bold**

Comment: Thanks Mari-Lou. I've just tried it for the first time. It's easier to type the asterisks. Using the icons for **bold** and *italics* is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word “quarticentennial” suggested by Ellie Kesselman above. Like the words decennial, every 10 years, and bicentennial, it’s a consistent pairing with the “-centennial “ or “-cennial” root and Latin prefixes.

However, a centennial is an event, celebrated at 100 years. Words with the “-cennial” root, like decennial, refer to a repeating cycle, e.g. every 10 years.

However, in the spirit of brevity, for a word describing the cycle of every 25 years, what about “quarcennial”? “Quarti-“ just stumbles when spoken. After all, we say “Quarter-horse”, not “Quarti-horse”. “Quartercennial” is perhaps most correct, every quarter-century.

Similarly, in the spirit of simplicity, albeit not word length, “quarter-centennial” to describe an event celebrated at 25 years is perhaps best of all, which was, I think, the original question.

Answer (score -1):

The term "quadrans" (like "quadrant") means a fourth or a quarter (it was the name of a Roman coin), so a quadranscentennial is a fourth of a centennial — i.e., 25 years.

Comment: Did you notice all the other answers with the same suggestion?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the coumpound noun 'quad-centary' may suffice, which seems akin to 'bi-centary' (50 years)

Comment: Neither _bi-centary_ nor _quad-centary_ is a word.