# What’s a 75th birthday called?

Tags: phrase-requests

Are there words for 75th and 50th birthdays? In particular, I’m looking for a word to describe the festivities, e.g. Diamond Jubilee, etc

More personally, my daughter and I are each celebrating those birthdays this year. What would a single party celebrating both birthdays be called?

Finally, is there a word describing events that occur every 25 years? For example, the decennial Census, every 10 years? 4 years? 50? Etc.

Comment: Please see [Is there a word for “25 years” like “bicentennial” for 200 years?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59554/is-there-a-word-for-25-years-like-bicentennial-for-200-years-is-it-quadran)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a common word for 75th [jubilees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee) or [anniversaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_anniversary#Celebration_and_gifts) analogous to silver, gold, etc, according to Wikipedia, although you'll find one for 50th.

Comment: Events called _jubilees_ or _anniversaries_ (as opposed to _birthdays_) usually commemorate some event in an adult's life, so that a 75th Jubilee for the Queen was a very unusual event, which Wikipedia, at least, calls a _[Platinum Jubilee_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum_Jubilee_of_Elizabeth_II), in contrast to Golden at 50. I don't know whether there's a special name for an alloy of gold and platinum; _electrum_ is gold and silver.

Comment: In Texas in 1986, we celebrated our state’s sesquicentennial, our 150th birthday. 


Therefore, the best I’ve got is calling a 75th birthday a Semisesquicentennial, but that’s a bit large, even for this 6th generation Texan.

Comment: Also, thank you, Weather Vane. I read and commented on the thread you mentioned.

Comment: My comment led me to recall and justify my suggestion of a semisesquicentennial birthday above .. I’m going with that .. y’all come on down to Galveston on The Strand and we’ll have us a time on Tuesday evening on August 31st